# fibonacci function by implementing Monad instance of a newtype

Tags: haskell

I just got into Monads and have been trying to convert a simple fibonacci function into a new one using Monads. In addition to getting the fibonacci number, I also want to get the number of recursions. So basically I am looking to combine the two functions

```
rec :: Int -> Int
rec n
  | n == 0 = 0
  | n == 1 = 0
  | otherwise = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2) + 2

fib :: Int -> Int
fib n
  | n == 0 = 0
  | n == 1 = 1
  | otherwise = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

to something like this

```
import Control.Monad

newtype Test a b = Test { getTest :: (b, a -> a) }
  deriving Functor

gett :: Test a b -> (b, a -> a)
gett =  getTest

instance Applicative (Test a) where
   pure = return
   (<*>) = liftM2 ($)

instance Monad (Test a) where
   return :: b -> Test a b
   --something like ?: return b = Test $ (b,\a -> a) 

   (>>=) :: Test a b -> (b -> Test a c) -> Test a c
   --something like ?: Test b >>= f = Test $  \a -> gett(f a)

add :: (a -> a) -> Test a ()
-- something like ?: add a = Test a ()

getFib :: Test a b -> b   --getFib (fib 10) -> 55
getFib = fst . getTest

getRec :: Test a b -> a -> a  --getRec (fib 10) 0 -> 176
getRec = snd . getTest

fib :: Int -> Test Int Int
fib n
  | n == 0 = return 0
  | n == 1 = return 1
  | otherwise = do
                a <- fib (n-1)
                add (+2)
                b <- fib (n-2)
                return (a+b)
```

I have been stuck on the implementation of return bind of the newType Test and add. My idea is that the Test Monad will accumulate the test function and focus on the computation of b. Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: The instance can be derived with [`-XDerivingVia`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia): `newtype Test a b = .. deriving (Functor, Foldable, Applicative, Monad, MonadFix, MonadZip) via Writer (Endo a)`. You can query further instances with the ghci command: `:instances Writer (Endo _)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your monad is essentially the `Writer (Endo a)` monad, up to isomorphism.

Your proposed definitions are mostly correct:

```
instance Monad (Test a) where
   return :: b -> Test a b
   --something like ?: 
   return b = Test $ (b,\a -> a)
```

Yes, that's correct. The identity is the neutral element of the endo monoid.

```
   (>>=) :: Test a b -> (b -> Test a c) -> Test a c
   --something like ?: 
   Test b >>= f = Test $  \a -> gett(f a)
```

No, this is not correct since you discard value `b`, and do not produce a pair. You want something like

```
Test (x, f) >>= g = Test (x', f' . f)    -- or f . f'
   where Test (x', f') = g x
```

Instead,

```
add :: (a -> a) -> Test a ()
-- something like ?: 
add a = Test a ()
```

looks correct.

That being said, here's a few suggestions:

- For your `fib` example, using your monad seem to be overkill. You are using `Writer (Endo a)` when `Writer (Sum Int)` would suffice. Instead of storing a function `a -> a` in your monadic type, you could simply store an `Int` and sum it in `>>=` to achieve the right count.
- You could reuse the monads from the libraries. Right now, you are reinventing them. Still, what you are doing right now is a great exercise to understand how the libraries work, so it's not pointless at all!